# How to render ERB view as string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, renderpartial

I am trying to convert dyanmic HTMl to PDF using wicked_pdf gem.

this is all i have

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @var = Hash.new
    @var = { first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", address: "A & N", country: "India" }
    html = render "home/to_pdf.html.erb", locals: { var:@var }, layout: false 
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html[0].to_s)

    save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
    File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf
    end

    render :home  # or redirect_to is also acceptable
  end
end
```

**to_pdf.html.erb**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .row {
        color: red;
    }
    .p {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div class="row">
    <em><%= @var[:first_name] %></em>
    <em><%= @var[:last_name] %></em>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <em><%= @var[:address] %></em>
    <em><%= @var[:country] %></em>
</div>
<div class="sign">
    <br><br>
    SIgn Here
</div>
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<h1>Pdf created successfully</h1>
```

it successfully render to_pdf.html.erb and successfuly create and saves the pdf file, but
i got **DoubleRenderError** which is obvious.

i want it to redirect_to or render to "home"

**Note:** if i remove render "home", then i got no error but then it renders **to_pdf.html.erb** not the index.html.erb.

i just want compiled erb view (which is dynamic as you can see above m using @var) as html so that i can convert it to pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

render `erb` for `pdf` you could try [render_to_string](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string)

Comment: oh my god, just one line changed the whole world, where have you been before, thanks a lot man.:)